# How can I clean the Parameters field in the Run -> Parameters menu?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2007

I'm using the CodeGear RAD Studio IDE.

In order to test my application with command line parameters I used a few times the "Parameters" field in the "Run -> Parameters" menu.

But every time I provide it with a new value, it could not be deleted from the "dropdown box".

I need to clean this field (erase all the values), since in some cases there is information on them that I don't want to share with people that occasionally could use my machine.

How can I clean this field?

Comment: Generic tooling: run SysInternals Process Monitor, filter by ide exe, then see in which files or registry branches the information is saved

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Delphi 2007 Parameters list is stored in the Windows registry in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0\History Lists\hlRunParameters` location

[image]

[image]

To clean that list remove the *ItemN* entries and set the value of the `Count` key to 0.