# Increase number of stored runtime parameters

Tags: delphi, ide

I am using this trick ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502689/how-to-manage-constantly-changing-project-run-time-parameters-in-the-ide) / [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637582/512728)) to store run-time parameters with annotations in registry key 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\History Lists\hlRunParameters` (Delphi-10-Seattle):

Whenever I edit a runtime parameter in the IDE it gets added as a new one to that list:

[image]

But recently I noticed that old ones disappear. It looks as if there is a maximum to the number of entries that Delphi maintains in that key (or maybe the total size of the entries has a limit)<sup>*</sup>.
(According to that screenshot only some 26 keys fit)

Is there a way to increase this number or work around this limitations?

<sup>* No, it is not an error in that tool I link to.</sup>